# Migrating standalone exhange 2007 to vCenter

Tags: exchange-2007, vmware-vcenter, vmware-converter

I need to migrate our last server to a center.
But i really not looking forward to move the last server.

It contains exchange 2007, ad, dhcp and dns.
Server os: windows 2003 R2 x64

It is to be moved out to our hosting center, so i'm planing to go out there with the virtual machine on a usb disk.

How is the best way to do this?

Do i just run Vmware Converter, and let all the services running, or should i do it by night booting it up in safe mode, and then use vmware converter?

Any experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend spinning up a new VM and promoting it to be a domain controller which will handle AD and DNS.  Then add DHCP to it.

Then install Exchange and migrate the mailboxes from the current server to the new server, with basically no down time.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
I did as you wrote, was a little time consuming, but now it clean and running very good.


Thx for your answer

Comment: No problem. Glad we got it done.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to perform a 'cold' conversion yes. 'Hot' ones are fine but in my experience 'cold' ones are more stable/predictable.

Comment: I thought so, but is it enough doing it in safe mode, because i don't have access to vmware converter boot cd

Comment: "Cold" conversion doesn't even boot the OS, it does it from its own boot CD. If you mean you'd like to do a 'hot' one from the safe mode I'd have to strongly advise against it.